# Programmatically set a percentage height to LinearLayout in a Widget's RemoteViews

Tags: java, android, android-studio, widget, remoteview

I want to create a widget with graphs which represent a percentage increase in stock value for certain assets. I was able to create an overview of graphs with each graph having a percentage height by putting two `LinearLayout`s in a container `LinearLayout`. The bottom `LinearLayout` is the graph and the top `LinearLayout` is the spacer which gets a certain `layout_weight`. This way I can reduce the size of the other container using percentages. (if the spacer has a `layout_weight` of `0.4`, then the graph is 60% high).

The current state of the widget is (I wanted to handle negative values in red afterwards, but no need to continue if I can't figure out how to percentually size the graphs) :

[image: An example of the current state of the widget.]

I chose this approach because I can't use `ConstraintLayout` in `RemoteViews`. Everything seemed to work nicely, but when I wanted to programmatically change the size of the spacer based on data from the api (so the sizes of the graphs truly match the percentage increase of the stock value), I wasn't able to. There is, as far as I could see, no way to change the `layout_weight` of a `LinearLayout` in a `RemoteView` in java.

I then thought maybe my last hope would be to find the container - which contains all the graphs - its height by using `findViewById`, but that's also not possible with `RemoteViews`. I then would've seen the container's height as `100%` and then set the height of the other `LinearLayout`s according to that size. 60% would be 0.6 times the height I fetched from the container. But that, I'm afraid, is also not possible.

So I actually have no clue how to programmatically find out how high a `LinearLayout` is or how I can change the size of a `LinearLayout` percentually. It seems like I always already need to know the sizes of the containers which will be used in the widget? Which is kind of annoying as the content varies and it needs to be rendered differently based on the ratio of each gain of each asset.

Am I missing a certain way to approach this? I can't seem to find much more on the Android Developers documentation... Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to affect things like that was only added in API Level 31 (Android 12), with methods like [`setViewLayoutHeight()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html?hl=en#setViewLayoutHeight(int,%20float,%20int)). So, one option would be to set your `minSdk` to be 31 and live with a smaller user base for a while.

Or:

- For a complex UI, you might consider rendering a `Bitmap` inside your app, then showing that `Bitmap` in an `ImageView` in the app widget (with the `Bitmap` served via a `ContentProvider`). This is annoying, but it gives you ultimate flexibility.
- Another possibility is to have a bunch of different layout resources, where you encode a range of desired weights, the use the desired one in the `RemoteViews` when you go to update it. If you keep consistent widget IDs, the rest of your code should not need to change much.
- You have the question tagged as [java](/questions/tagged/java). If you eventually learn Kotlin, you could see if Glance has some more flexibility. Glance uses Jetpack Compose to create app widgets (and Wear OS tiles).

Comment: The rest of the app is fully usable, I can't force users to not be able to use our app just for the widget I'm afraid.

- 1 Would rendering a `Bitmap` give me the possibility to use percentage-height layouts inside that `Bitmap`? Is it possible to draw with percentages on that canvas?

- 2 Would I be able to render a different graph for each layout resource? Then I could work with 5% increments and take the closest number idd.

- 3 The app is entirely made in React-Native, so I wouldn't mind trying Kotlin if I know it would fix my problem. I made the widget without any Java knowledge.

Comment: @Kevin: "Would rendering a Bitmap give me the possibility to use percentage-height layouts inside that Bitmap? Is it possible to draw with percentages on that canvas?" -- sure. Everything you see in an Android UI (minus `SurfaceView`/`TextureView`) was drawn to a `Canvas`. You can even create a traditional XML layout, inflate it, then render that resulting `View` to a `Canvas`. "Would I be able to render a different graph for each layout resource?" -- I do not know what that means, sorry. "The app is entirely made in React-Native" -- then please tag your questions as such.

Comment: Do you think you could point me to an example where a (rounded) rectangle is drawn on a `Canvas` in a `RemoteViews` in a widget? Can't really seem to find the correct terms to Google how to execute that suggestion of yours. Eg. A rectangle with 60% height of its parent. -- The widget has nothing to do with the rest of the app being made using RN, right? That's why I didn't tag it as such. I only wanted to mention that I'm not necessarily bound to Java so I'm definitely open to trying Kotlin to achieve this.

Comment: @Kevin: "Do you think you could point me to an example where a (rounded) rectangle is drawn on a Canvas in a RemoteViews in a widget?" -- that is rather niche, so it is unlikely that there is such an example. You might try breaking the problem down into pieces. For example, [this post](https://medium.com/over-engineering/getting-started-with-drawing-on-the-android-canvas-621cf512f4c7) covers `Canvas` and using it to draw to a bitmap. You then need to learn how to draw the rounded rectangle on the `Canvas` and how to show the `Bitmap` in a `RemoteViews`.

Comment: @Kevin: "The widget has nothing to do with the rest of the app being made using RN, right?" -- earlier, you wrote "The app is entirely made in React-Native". I have not used React Native, but in ordinary Android app development, the app widget is part of the app. Since you don't have any code in your question, "The app is entirely made in React-Native" suggests that you were creating the app widget in React Native, and I have limited ability to help with that environment.

Comment: I've tried out Glance, but the problem is that you're stuck using GlanceModifiers and can't use the regular Jetpack Compose Modifiers. I've tried out using a Canvas, but I don't think this enables me to do much more? And I fear it would remove some of the resizing possibilities I have right now. Is there truly no possibility whatsoever to eg. have render a container inside a RemoteViews, with inside that container a plain rectangle which has a percentage size of its parent?... That's the bare minimum I've been trying to replicate these last few weeks.

Comment: @Kevin: "have render a container inside a RemoteViews, with inside that container a plain rectangle which has a percentage size of its parent?" -- `LinearLayout` and careful use of `android:layout_weight` can accomplish that, as you note in your question. Your problem is in how you're trying to *change* that, and `RemoteViews` simply is not set up for that sort of structural change. Have you tried using a set of PNGs representing bars of varying percentages, then swapping in the desired PNG when you want to change the bar percentage>

Comment: I just tried some PNG fiddling, no avail. Also images get very unsharp immediately in comparison to LinearLayout. I had some hope actually for that approach... I'm totally baffled this is blocking me. Never though when I was about to try to create a widget it would be so insanely primitive. Thanks though for thinking with me. Actually one last idea I might have is to have your PNG idea reversed. Instead of having the charts as PNG, I could have the "spacers" as PNGs filled with the background colour, or maybe even completely transparent. My last hope. I'll let you know.

Comment: That approach seems to work  that's an awesome hack. Thanks for giving me the idea to use PNGs! I'm going to find a formula which adds certain height spacers. I'm probably going to try to add a certain amount of different sized black backgrounds as spacers to calculate the amount I need. I guess it's best to limit the amount of images I render for performance reasons... Anyway, thanks for thinking with me! 

Comment: @Kevin: I'm glad it's working out!

Answer (score 0):

Use directly :
view.setViewLayoutHeightDimen(your layoutId, int heightDimen)